# Issue with C++ Srand Values

Tags: c++, random, time, srand

So I'm creating a lottery ticket with random values and then sorting it. I'm not worried about the sorting technique since the teacher isn't looking for classes etc. on this assignment and it works, however, my ticket values that I produce - despite using srand (time(0)) and then later the rand() % 40 + 1 - which I think should make my randoms between 1-40... but mainTicket[0] always equals 0. Any ideas? Sorry about the formatting, made me add extra spaces and mess up my indention.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void mainLotto (int main[]);
void lottoSort (int ticketArr[]);

int main()
{
int mainTicket[5];

srand (time(0));

mainLotto(mainTicket);

do
{
    lottoSort(mainTicket);
} while (mainTicket[0] > mainTicket[1] || mainTicket[1] > mainTicket[2] || mainTicket[2] > mainTicket[3] || mainTicket[3] > mainTicket[4] || mainTicket[4] > mainTicket[5]);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << mainTicket[i] << "\n\n";
}

return 0;
}

///
/// <> Creates the actual lottery ticket
///
void mainLotto (int main[])
{
// Creating the ticket
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    main[i] = rand() % 40 + 1;
}
}

///
/// <> Sorts the actual lottery ticket
///
void lottoSort (int ticketArr[])
{
 // Sorting the ticket
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    if (ticketArr[j] > ticketArr[j+1])
    {
        int temp;

        temp = ticketArr[j+1];

        ticketArr[j+1] = ticketArr[j];

        ticketArr[j] = temp;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `ticketArr[j+1]` goes out of bounds

Comment: Just a tip for further consideration: Try limiting yourself to a sane line-length like 80 or so, especially on code you post online. Focing readers to scroll horizontally is really bad mojo. Also, proper indentation (pick one of the common styles, like K&R), consistently applied is really helpful, not only here but also for yourself.

Comment: I do use a constant form of indentation, but I don't indent the very first things, which I have to do for coding here. I may start doing it for future use here though, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems with your arrays being accessed out of bounds:

**Here:**

```
int main()
{
    int mainTicket[5];

    srand(time(0));

    mainLotto(mainTicket);

    do
    {
        lottoSort(mainTicket);
    }
    while(mainTicket[0] > mainTicket[1] || mainTicket[1] > mainTicket[2]
        || mainTicket[2] > mainTicket[3] || mainTicket[3] > mainTicket[4]);
//      || mainTicket[4] > mainTicket[5]); // OUT OF BOUNDS!!!

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << mainTicket[i] << "\n\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**And here:**

```
void lottoSort(int ticketArr[])
{
    // Sorting the ticket
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) // j < 4 NOT 5!!! <== WAS OUT OF BOUNDS
    {
        if(ticketArr[j] > ticketArr[j + 1])
        {
            int temp;

            temp = ticketArr[j + 1];

            ticketArr[j + 1] = ticketArr[j];

            ticketArr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Likely the sort routine was dragging in a zero from out side the array bounds.

Comment: Wow, I missed the conditional statement as well... it works like a charm now, thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

I just printed the item you claim to be always zero, after the `mainLotto()` and it yielded 30.

I suspect the problem lies where you tell us not to look. :)

In the sorting function you do:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    if (ticketArr[j] > ticketArr[j + 1]) {
```

The array is of size 5. Your `j` will take eventually a value equal to 4.

Then you do `ticketArr[j + 1]`, which is actually an **out of bound** access.

The fix is to go until 4 in your loop, not 5.

As Galik said, `mainTicket[4] > mainTicket[5]` is also an out of bounds access and after reading my answer, you should be able to understand why. :)

Comment: Ah, I totally missed that! Any suggestions on how I can rewrite it to make sure I never go out of bounds? Trying combination of j and j-1 but I'm not having much success.

Comment: Your loop should go until 4, not 5. @ldehart